# How can I convert a Git repository with branches to a workable Mercurial repository?

Tags: git, mercurial, branch, dvcs, mercurial-convert

I want to convert a Git repository with several branches to a Mercurial repository. Using `hg convert` only one default branch is created which then has a head for each Git branch.

I have already read [How are git branches imported into mercurial with hg convert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743876/how-are-git-branches-imported-into-mercurial-with-hg-convert) and am aware that it is impossible to know which commit belongs to which branch in Git. However, a repository with as many heads as branches is not a workable solution for me.

Since all branches are different, I obviously can not merge them all to one single head.

How can I convert or modify the converted repository in such a way that I have each head on a different branch? Note that I do not necessarily need to have all existing commits assigned to the right branch but that I want commits from this moment on to be assigned to the right branch and only have one head per branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** to know some things about Git:

- Git "branches" are not branches for any other *good* VCS, for Mercurial, f.e they are bookmarks by nature ("branch" mark only head-changeset and any older changeset doesn't contain this metadata)
- When Git-boy speak about branches - he lies, because branches are branches only in his Git-world
- Noboby (today) will convert Git-"branches" into branches on converting repositories
- In most cases (except very exotic Git-repos) `hg-git` instead Convert Extension will produce more correct (bidirectional) conversion

Specially for you I repeated operations from (excellent in common) [VonC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745074/960558) in linked by you question and will show you some pictures (Git's from SmartGit, Mercurial's from TortoiseHG)

After all commits,

```
GitRepo>git log --oneline
79ea101 third evolution in branch 2
720ac25 second evolution in branch 2
48951c3 first evolution in branch 2
6cf26b0 first content, to be evolved in three different branches
```

before importing to Mercurial, with all "branches"

[image: Git-repo]

From Mercurial's POV, results of import is very different: repository have one **real branch** (named branch `default`) and 3 anonymous branches in it, marked with *Mercurial bookmarks* br1-br2-br3.

[image: HG-repo]

You must to create named branches and rewrite history by hand, if you want to use Mercurial named branches in this repository:

- commit new empty changesets as descendants of 0, they will be starting point of branches
- rebase anonymous branches to these new parents (change actual branches)

[image: Rebased HG-repo]

As optional and the last step you can remove created at step 1 empty changesets (`histedit` do it well) and all *useless* bookmarks

[image: Clean HG-repo]

Comment: Thanks a lot, great explanation! The history rewriting was the part I was missing on the other question.

Comment: @Chris - BTW, you can (theoretically) automate **all** parts of history changes, except interactive by design histedit